# Does almost surely convergence implies convergence in $L^p$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I have the following excercise:
Does almost surely convergence imply convergence in $L^p$? Prove or give a counterexample.

For $0 < p < ∞$, we say $X_n$ converges in $L^p$ to $X$ if $X ∈ L^p(Ω)$ and $\Bbb E|Xn − X|^p → 0$ as $n → ∞$

I think it's not true, but I can't get a counterexample.
Could you provide any?

I know it is not true that convergence in probability implies almost surely convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly not true. For example, take a sequence of measurable sets $\Omega \supseteq A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq A_3 \supseteq \cdots$ Such that $\mathbb{P}(A_n) = \frac{1}{n}$. Now let $X_n$ be the random variable given by $X_n := n^{1/p} \cdot \mathbf{1}_{A_n}$, where $\mathbf{1}$ denotes an indicator function.

It is easy to see that $X_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s., but for all $n$ we have that:

$$\begin{align} \mathbb{E}|X_n - 0|^p & = \mathbb{E}(n \cdot \mathbf{1}_{A_n})\\
& = n \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_n) \\
& = 1  \end{align}$$

Comment: omg. That's a good example very useful.
Thank you.